# JPA @ElementCollection: How to hold insertion order

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to store a LinkedHashMap of user-defined key-value parameters. For that I created a dynamic html jquery-based table allowing the user to either create a new "key-value-row", deleting an existing one or moving the rows up or down.

Now, I am able to map the DOM-ids inputfields to my persistence entity, a map, annotated with @ElementCollection. Unfortunately - after refreshing the page - there seems to be an arbitrary order which is not acceptable as long as I enable the user to move key,value-pairs to a specific index.

This is my JPA-Entity's map member variable:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name="VCTRL_SELECTIONBOXES_VALUEMAP",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="SELECTIONBOXES_ID")
)
@Column(name="MAP_VALUE")
@MapKeyColumn(name="MAP_KEY")
private Map<String, String> valueMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Do you have any kind of idea how to cope with that?

Comment: SQL tables do not have an order - you have to define it. So you have to sort it: You could try using `@OrderColumn(name = "xxx")`

Comment: But a collection table ´for maps does only have two columns for key and values. don't want to sort for keys but for insertion order...

Comment: Then add another column which contains the create timestamp, and order by this one. SQL doesn't have a notion of "insertion order".

Comment: When I refresh the tables they are shown in they right order as I put it into my table. The problem occures when reading the data again into my map. You mean a empty column with a default value, right?

Comment: AFAIK a `LinkedHashMap` is not sorted either (look for `SortedMap` or `TreeMap`). Anyway, I mean a column in your table, say `createTimestamp`, filled by JPA (or even by the DB using a trigger or default value). Then if you select from that table, just order by `createTimestamp`. Put the result in an appropriate collection which is sorted as well (SortedMap backed by TreeMap with a Comparator for example).

Answer (score 1):

`createTimestamp` wont help with order - you cannot move rows up and down and rely on sorting by it. Seems your only option is to create separate object with integer column 'order' and fill it before saving, then order by it when loading. But it will probably not work with `CollectionTable`, use standard `OneToMany`.